# Find a number from a string using php

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regular expressions in PHP.

My problem is that I'm trying to find a number from a string. I got an address ex : 25 Down Street , London .

I want to only catch the number of the street which is here 25, but it also can be 1 or 2500 for example .

The number is always at the beginning of the address it's always the first "word" .

Comment: You can use `\d+` to capture any combination of digits. start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Why do you apologize for being new in the field of regular expressions? No need to do so! Don't! However what you _should_ do prior to asking this is: take a look at the existing questions and answers about regular expression, look through a few tutorials and examples and first start yourself to find a solution. This is not rocket science. Then, if you get stuck with your specific code, _then_ is the time to ask here :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to grab the number from the beginning of the string:

```
^\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/mF1rR6/1

The `^` anchors to the *beginning* of the string and `\d+` matches *one or more digits* at that position.

Here is a great resource for getting into regular expressions:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer and both websites , really usefull !

Answer (score 1):

As the number is always at the beginning of the string, you can do a simple trick like below. But of course if you want to do it without regex.

```
echo '10 Foo Bar Road' + 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex as mentioned by @dustmouse, or you can use pure PHP if the number is **always** the first "word":

```
$address = '10 Foo Bar Road';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($address));
$number = intval($arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 <?php

 $string = '25 Down Street , London';
 $str =preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string);
 echo $str;
 ?>
```

Comment: An explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This does not answer the question. All your code does is REMOVE the numbers from a string. The asker wants to find the number in a string.

Comment: referring to php documentation , preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php , so when you use it like that you just keep the Number and strip others , of course , there are so many ways to do that

Comment: Wes Foster , this code doesn't remove the numbers from string